# How many group homomorphisms are there from $\Bbb Z/ 2\Bbb Z \times\Bbb Z/ 2\Bbb Z$ to $S_{4}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't even know how to define the function between  $\Bbb Z/ 2\Bbb Z \times\Bbb Z/ 2\Bbb Z$ to $S_{4}$. Can anyone helps me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a  homomorphism from $\Bbb  Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ to $S_4$, then $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2/\ker f \cong \text{Image}  f $

Now $|\ker f|=1,2,4$.

If $|\ker f|=1$ then $|\text{Image}  f |=4$  and $\text{Image}  f$ is a subgroup of $S_4$.

In a homomorphism $o(f(a))$ divides $o(a)$ foral $a$.Hence the  subgroups possible of order $4$ in $S_4$is $\{e,(12),(34),(12)(34)\},\{(e,(13),(24),(13)(24)\},\{e,(14),(23),(14)(23)\}$

If  $|\ker f|=2$ then $\ker f=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ or $\ker f=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ or $\ker f=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

For the first one we can define $f$ as $f(0,0)=e=f(1,0)$ ;$f(0,1) =$ Any of the two order elements namely any two cycle or any product of disjoint two cycles $(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)$.No of two cycles =6

So in total $9$ choices.

Similarly for the second one we have $9$ choices .

For the $3rd$ one we have $f(0,0)=e=f(1,1)$ and we can have $f(1,0)=f(0,1)=$ Any of the 9 elements.

If  $|\ker f|=4$;then $f(a)=e\forall a\in \Bbb  Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$

Thus we have total $3+3\times 9+1=31$ homomorphisms

Comment: I have tried to be as precise as possible ;Please check if there is any gap in the arguments

Comment: For your first case, there are other possible images, e.g. $\{e,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$; and for each possible image, there are $6=|\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb ℤ/2\mathbb ℤ \times \mathbb ℤ/2 \mathbb ℤ)|$ different maps $f$ with the same image.

Comment: I believe there are four possible images of order 4, namely the three currently listed in your answer and the one you wrote before.  And there are six homomorphisms onto each one of them (send $(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$ to the three non-identity elements of the image in any order), which gives $(4 \cdot 6) + (3 \cdot 9) + 1 = 52$.

Comment: In your previous comment you wrote correct answer is $100$;now you are telling $52$;???@RaviFernando

Comment: Yes, I originally thought the answer was 100, by the same argument as Bernard's.  But after looking at your (correct) answer to a related question about homomorphisms from $D_4$ to $S_3$, I realized I had made a mistake, which I explained in a comment on Bernard's answer.  My apologies.

Comment: I don't understand this part: $\ker f=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$or$\ker f=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$or$\ker f=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$, Why ker f can be two elements?@learnmore

Comment: I mean, why $ker f$ cannot be {$(1,0),(1,1)$}?

Comment: $\ker f$ is a subgroup and a subgroup must contain zero element of the group which is $(0,0)$ here@梁楷葳

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $S_4$, and say $f(1,0) = a$, $f(0,1) = b$, and $f(1,1) = c$.  (Of course, $f(0,0) = e$, the identity.)  In order for this to be a homomorphism, we must have $f(gh) = f(g) f(h)$ for all elements $g$ and $h$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.  This amounts to the information that $a^2 = b^2 = e$ and $c = ab = ba$.  (There are lots of conditions you can write down, but the rest all follow from these.)  So $f$ is determined completely by the two elements $a$ and $b$, and any two such elements will work as long as $a^2 = b^2 = e$ and $ab = ba$.

In $S_4$, there are ten elements that square to the identity:  the identity itself, six transpositions, and three double-transpositions.  So $a$ and $b$ must be some pair chosen from among these ten, such that they commute (i.e. $ab = ba$).  Let's check which pairs commute.  The identity commutes with everything.  If $a$ is a single transposition, say $(12)$, you can check that it only commutes with itself, the identity, the "opposite" transposition ($(34)$ in this case), and the product $(12)(34)$.  Finally, if $a$ is a double transposition, then it commutes with the identity, the two single transpositions it is composed of, and all of the double transpositions.  So $a = e$ gives 10 choices for $b$; each of the 6 transpositions give 4 choices for $b$; and each of the 3 double transpositions give 6 choices for $b$.  This yields a total of $(1 \cdot 10) + (6 \cdot 4) + (3 \cdot 6) = 52$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying the necessary conditions, so there are 52 homomorphisms $f:  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to S_4$.